# Service running in localhost is not accessible through postman client

Tags: java, rest, jboss7.x, postman

I have a REST service running in the localhost. I'm able to connect/access the service with a JavaScript client.

But the service is not accessible through postman client.

HTTP Request

```
POST /VsaServiceProject/rest/vsa-service/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c71ed13c-868f-2502-97e1-d2dcec50a462

{
    "userCode" : "stud01",
    "password" : "1234"
}
```

Service Method

```
@PermitAll
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/auth")
public Response login(User user) {

      ...
      ...
      ...

      return Response.ok(json.toString()).build();

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You'll need to post the REST service code? How have you called the REST service? Which HTTP Method have you used? POST? GET?

Comment: It is a POST method. @morsor

Comment: Did you try posting to `/VsaServiceProject/auth`?

Comment: I didn't try that. but `/VsaServiceProject/rest/vsa-service/auth` worked with my client JavaScript application